# Amazon EC2 getting all blocked IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

My project back-end developed with nodejs, it has stored on AWS EC2 instance. Server is running and it's also access everywhere but from last day i can't access from a particular IP address?

if that IP address is blocked how can i get block list IP address or remove the blocked IP ?

Comment: Why is your question the same as [networking - Amazon EC2 getting all blocked IP addresses? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388301/amazon-ec2-getting-all-blocked-ip-addresses)? Is this an actual business problem, or a sample exam question?

Comment: i'm astonished, he is  facing same type of problem same time. Actually i don't know about that

Answer (score 2):

If an IP address is blocked then you might want to check two places which are responsible for this :

1. Security Group.
2. NACL.

Security Group is the firewall which blocks traffic at Instance Level. Whereas NACL blocks the traffic at Subnet Level.

Look for the inbound rule to find out whether your specific IP is being denied at these levels.

Answer (score 2):

1.Open your VPC dashboard
2.Open the “Network ACLs” view
3.Open the ACL editor
4.Select the subnet to which your EC2 instances or load balancers are connected.
5.Click “Inbound Rules”

There you can see the IP addresses which are blocked

Comment: In ACL, there are  6 subnets  associated , i click the subnets associated show  all subnets  and click my subnet but no inbound Rules. Again 

in ACL inbound Rules, show only  one Rules 100 with All Traffic 

There are no block list here

Comment: Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the AWS WAF console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/wafv2/.

In the navigation pane, choose Rules.

In the Name column, choose a rate-based rule.

The list shows the IP addresses that the rule currently blocks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your VPC dashboard
2. Open the “Network ACLs” view
3. Open the ACL editor

   - Select the subnet to which your EC2 instances or load balancers are connected.
   - Click “Inbound Rules”
   - Click “Edit”
4. Add a rule to allow the traffic Or Remove your IP if exist

**OR**

Check the iptables of your EC2 instance
[click here for more about iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/163111/allow-traffic-to-from-specific-ip-with-iptables)

Comment: For check the iptables, i write the command in  terminal /etc/init.d/iptables status
   output show No such file or directory. What will i do ?

Comment: TRY WITH FIREWALLD :

"firewall-cmd --get-active-zones"
Then try the following:

"firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent"
Don't forget to replace the zone and the port with the one you are looking for. After that you need to reload the firewall:

"firewall-cmd --reload"